# How to give permission of a folder to a specific user in LINUX/UNIX?

Tags: permissions

How can I give permission to a specific user for a particular folder?

I don't want to give permission to the entire group but only to a particular user in the group.

I don't have root permissions.

Answer (score 6):

Use an [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list), these are supported by most Unix derivatives. There is a decent introduction to ACLs on Linux [here](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html), and a (more Arch-specific, but still useful) guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACL).

Comment: The links given by @chris give excellent examples.  Here is a simple example for setting read/write permissions for a user named john on a file named test.c:  setfacl -m u:john:rw test.c